# How do people import lots of data (ETL) into a database from an ASP.NET website?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, background, etl

**Problem**: We wish to do some ETL (extract, transform, load) with some csv data, where the process kicks off manually via a webpage in an ASP.NET website.

**Context**

We have an ASP.NET website that includes a restricted `Admin` section.

In this section, we wish to add a page which will allow a person to click-a-button to select file(s) which are to be imported into a Sql Server DB Table.

Some of these files could contain lots of rows - 500,000. (Each row is about 300-400 characters long, over about 13 or so 'columns' .. csv'd.).

Now, importing this could take a while. It's like, I wish to upload the file content to some place and then some background task kicks off.

I'm wondering how people are doing this, now?

We are on Azure, so we can access Azure blobs and queues and webjobs i guess. Just not sure if this is a common problem that has been tackled heaps of times and there's some reference material out there to review.

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume you have the CSV parsing figured out (use CSV Helper or similar tool). But the part you have trouble with is how to handle this long running task in a website, when the normal page interaction runs all in a request/response lifecycle. But parsing a big CSV file is just too long for a normal request/response lifecycle.

Yes, this is a solved problem. There are a quite a few tools on Azure you can use for this, you've mentioned some of them. You can also kick off an external application to do the processing, perhaps using message queues. But you can also do it entirely in ASP.NET. Scott Hanselman has a [great blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx) on this subject. It boils down to using some sort of library that's designed to handle the perils of running in ASP.NET without an HTTP Context safely, and usually picking a tool that can survive application crashes. Libraries like Quartz.NET and [Hangfire](http://hangfire.io/).

Essentially, with these sorts of libraries, you kick a job off to do the processing, and you can check back later when it's completed.

Comment: bingo .. this is getting somewhere now :) You're correct re: the parsing. That's all sorted. You're (again) correct that the problem is handling long running tasks in a website. Ok, I've heard of Q and H but I'm _hoping_ to leverage something similar in Azure. I'll read SH's post and pop back later with more info. BTW - thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Well its easy. i face this problem before.

long way:

1._ Upload the file.

2._ take the file do your validations

3._ Convert to a datatable (I really dont remember the name of the library i used)

4._ Use native bulks of sql (no ORMS its really simple and fast)

notes : be sure the webconfig its configured to support heavy files.

short way:
Use SSRS an create a package that takes an csv and map the fields to the table

Answer (score 0):

Do all ETL processes in a single tool such as SSIS. It will be a nightmare to deal your custom ETL tools later on. Or your website can trigger SSIS ETL. Make your website drop the file in a location SSIS can pick up.

[SSIS for Azure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj901708.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use SSIS, but you are using EF, you could use [CsvHelper](http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/). To quicken the import via EF, set `AutoDetectChangesEnabled` to `false` for the dbContext you use for the import. I have used this, and my import runs pretty much instantaneous although my data contains under 100k records, and varying between 5 to 20 columns.

I wrote a [CsvHelperWrapper](https://github.com/frankfajardo/CsvHelperWrapper/blob/master/CsvImportUtility/ImportHandler.cs) which has an `ImportHandler` class. This class has an `ImportAsync` method which accepts a file path, and other parameters, and performs certain EF function before calling the CsvHelper. But in your case, you'd replace the file path with a stream reader.

I use my ImportHandler in a windows service, which also defines a custom configuration section where I can define all details it needs to pass to ImportHandler for each file it needs to import (e.g., where to get the csv file from, what file name pattern maps to which entity class, should it assume the csv file has header row, should it trim data from csv, etc.) But you can ask your user those details, then run the import in the background afterwards.

With this approach, for each new import file I needed to process, I simply write the entity class to receive it, and EF will create it for me if the backend table does not yet exist. And if, say you wish to validate the imported data in relation to other data in your database, you can write that and call it after import.

Comment: I'm also ready using CsvHelper so I totally know what you mean. Using Dapper instead of EF. But don't want to use a windows service :( Was hoping for something in Azure.

Comment: No reason why you can't use the above in a WebAPI.